# Print specific DOM element using JavaScript which has canvas and swf file

Tags: javascript

Print specific DOM element using JavaScript which has canvas and swf file

Suppose I have DIV(has id ABCReport) in my UI Report section contains some HTML/CSS with canvas and swf.
I done code around this able to print DIV section but only part which has SWF is blank.

Why canvas, swf are not print by normal browser printjob?

Comment: this is maybe because browser needs flash plugins to display swf animations... canvas is pure javascript, browser knows natively how to display it...

Comment: I think, Flash is already installed that's why showing in my page. I am using FusionChart this chart is not printing on printjob

Comment: You may have Flash installed but the browser doesn't know how to print it. Generally one gets a screen grab of the page and prints that if flash content is to be printed. Adobe even addresses this in their help pages: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/cant-print-flash-content-google.html. Specifically for Chrome but I wouldn't be surprised if firefox has the issue as well.